# FFMPEG Converted MP3 file shows error "MPEG header 30 is missing"

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using `FFMPEG` to convert all kind of media files to mp3. Files are being Converted Perfectly.
But files give error `MPEG HEADER 30 is missing at 31576bytes`. In All converted files I see this. And On Some MP3 Players, It do not play.

Here is my conversion Command what i use

```
$bitrate = '128k';    
$command = "ffmpeg -i /home/musicupl/public_html/musicuploads/SavetoAccount/abc.mp4 -ar 44100  -ac 2 -b:a ".$bitrate." -acodec libmp3lame /home/musicupl/public_html/musicuploads/SavetoAccount/Output.mp3;
```

Is there any more tag to add MPEG Headers during the conversion. I have researched on this and found the `-acodec libmp3lame` but still same issue.

Is there any other way or attribute to add in command line.

Comment: 1) What is giving you the error `MPEG HEADER 30 is missing at 31576bytes`? 2) Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command. 3) Provide a link to one of the troublesome input files if possible.

Comment: @llogan Here are the links of the Snapshot of FFMPEG Command... 
[Image 1](https://prnt.sc/10yqioo)  [Image 2](https://prnt.sc/10yqjro)   [Image 3](https://prnt.sc/10yqk8f)

Comment: @llogan I have added the 3 Images of the SSH Screen for the Command to Convert. Kindly check and Let me know if you can recommend something

Comment: Images of text are much less helpful than just copying and pasting the text. Your ffmpeg is ancient. You should upgrade before doing anything else. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). What is giving you the error `MPEG HEADER 30 is missing at 31576bytes`?